# Firebase coroutines onSuccessListener error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I've been getting this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it
 at com.bumtzihaus.app.data.AdminRepository.addLogItem_gIAlu_s$lambda-4(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.bumtzihaus.app.data.AdminRepository.$r8$lambda$34A54R8CS3e1Wdzy3o1dgUPicmE(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.bumtzihaus.app.data.AdminRepository$$ExternalSyntheticLambda8.onSuccess(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.0:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

for certain firestore queries; it's worked fine and all of a sudden I keep getting this error.
Here's what I'm trying to call:

```
    ref.set(
        hashMapOf(
            "logCode" to bumtziLog.logCode,
            "timestamp" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            "itemText" to bumtziLog.items,
            "users" to bumtziLog.users,
            "sessions" to bumtziLog.sessions
        )
    ).addOnSuccessListener {
        result = Result.success(Unit)
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        result = Result.failure(exception)
        exception.printStackTrace()
        Firebase.crashlytics.recordException(exception)
    }.await()
```

It seems to be complaining about a null lambda for onSuccessListener

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an error on Google's part - update to the latest Firebase version and you should get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps, but try to add explicit nullable parameter of type `Any?` for `addOnSuccessListener` lambda:

```
ref.set(
    hashMapOf(
        "logCode" to bumtziLog.logCode,
        "timestamp" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        "itemText" to bumtziLog.items,
        "users" to bumtziLog.users,
        "sessions" to bumtziLog.sessions
    )
).addOnSuccessListener { someResult: Any? ->
    result = Result.success(Unit)
}.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    result = Result.failure(exception)
    exception.printStackTrace()
    Firebase.crashlytics.recordException(exception)
}.await()
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70369150/8338411) answer works but if you don't want to add the parameter on each on success. Just upgrade you firestore gradle dependencies to the latest. In my situation I upgraded com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.2 to com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3 and everything worked out.